# Use body page like a button

Tags: jquery

I use below code to use my page like a button but the problem is that when I click on other buttons this function works too, what do you suggest? `document.body.onmousedown = function()`

Comment: Are you using jQuery on your page? If you are, look at [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: Stop the event from bubbling up.

Comment: @Mooseman: yeah I use

Comment: @j08691: what do you mean ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, see http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery example:

```
// Stop bubbling with event.stopPropagation(); on inner buttons
$("#selector").on('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Run your code
});

$("body").on('click', function(){
    // Run your code
});
```

Comment: Are you using the first for *all* of your other functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Mooseman suggested but you'll have to add `.stopPropagation()` to all in-page handlers so here's another solution.

Use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to detect the source of the event like this:

```
$('body').on('click',function(e){
    if (e.target === document.body) {
        alert('body clicked');
    }
});
```

or using nodeName:

```
if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'BODY') {
```

or jQuery way:

```
if ($(e.target).is('body')) {
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VLFtz/)